# Teradata Temporal Table migration

Tags: teradata, database-migration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, temporal-tables, teradatasql

**Teradata Temporal Table migration to Snowflake.**

I am doing migration of Teradata database to Snowflake using infoworks. I want to move my Teradata Temporal Tables as well while maintaining the consistency. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add more information? What kind of consistency are you referring to? What data types are you using? etc

Comment: By consistent, I mean all the columns(including the special column of type Period) and all historical rows must be same after the migration. I hope that makes it clear.

Comment: Snowflake has [time travel](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-time-travel.html), but there's no direct relationship between Teradata temporal tables and Snowflake time travel.

Comment: So, how should I migrate these table keeping the data integrety intact. Can I ingest the table as SCD type 2. Will that work?

Comment: There is a ton of Teradata to SF migrations out there and so all historical rows and columns can be mapped.

I think you need to start tracking the issues and identifying solutions for each one. For example period is two timestamps. You can map that to a string separated by a comma and then use a UDF for BEGIN/END.

SQLMorph (my free tool) is actually releasing that specific translation on Monday: https://www.phdata.io/sqlmorph-signup/

Comment: Snowflake does not have PERIOD data types. Using Teradata's BEGIN and END functions to extract the two Dates / Timestamps into separate columns would let you preserve the contents. SCD Type 2 may work for loading, but don't forget to change all the references to the table to take this into account.